# "The set $\{0,1\}^{10^{10}}$ of all bit strings of length $10^{10}$ " meaning?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, binary

I have a proof to do but I'm not sure about the meaning of the statement above, does it imply simply "The set of all 0s and 1s with the length of $10^{10}$ "?

Comment: Yes, the set $A^n$ is effectively $A\times A\times \cdots \times A$ where $\times$ here is a cartesian product, and is as such effectively the set of all sequences of length $n$ where each term in the sequence is from $A$.  In particular when $A$ happens to be $\{0,1\}$ and in particular when $n$ happens to be $10^{10}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly! $X^n$ is the set $\underbrace{X \times X \cdots \times X}_{\text{n times}}$.

Equivalently, it is the set of functions $f : \{1,2,\ldots,n\} \to X$, but these are the same thing because we can identify a function $f$ with the tuple $(f(1), f(2), \ldots, f(n))$.

Either way, for $\{0,1\}^5$ this is the set of all $(b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4, b_5)$ with each $b_i \in \{0,1\}$. This is exactly the set of binary strings of length 5!

Similarly, in your case $\{0,1\}^{10^{10}}$ is exactly the set of strings of length $10^{10}$.